# node-waf nodejs failing

Tags: ubuntu, node.js, web-application-firewall

When trying to compile Gilt Hummingbird for NodeJS, I get this error, as node-waf is missing.

```
rm -rf build .lock-wscript bson.node
node-waf configure build
make[1]: node-waf: Command not found
make[1]: *** [all] Error 127
```

I'm unsure how to compile or install node-waf correctly. I have tried compiling from source, but not seemed to work.

Ubuntu 10.10, NodeJS v0.2.5, nodejs-dev installed.

Comment: Has anyone made any progress with this? I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to this page

http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.2.5/api.html#addons-313

"node-waf is just http://code.google.com/p/waf/[WAF], the python-based build system. node-waf is provided for the ease of users."

So, you should have node-waf somewhere, but it probably isn't installed in the PATH, and so, this particular build can't find it.

You might want to try:

export PATH=$PATH:/wherever/node-waf/lives

And then retry the build.